# DateTime Parse to US format 'error', returns me non US format

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime, format

I have a problem parsing string to DateTime to US format. Although I provide the string in format of MM/dd/yyyy it keeps returning me the DateTime in format of dd/MM/yyyy and I have tried all of the below.

```
string[] formats = { "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "MM/dd/yyyy" };
DateTime dateTime;
var ex = DateTime.TryParseExact("12/29/1989", formats, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
```

And the above will return me the dateTime as "29/12/1989";

I have also tried:

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("12/29/1989", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

basicly I have tried all the DateTime Parse option and will all return me non us format.

I am based in th UK and my machine's locale is en-UK.

Comment: So you want to show the date in a specific format, while the parsing is OK?

Comment: What is your `provider` exactly? Looks like it is different than `en-US` and that's why your `DateTime`'s string representations are different.

Comment: What you mean with `it keeps returning me the DateTime in format of dd/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: I would like to convert any date of variable string of format MM/dd/yyy to DateTime. For ex I want to convert string "10/22/2014" to DateTime keeping the US formatting, but what happens is the parsing worksy only that the order of formatting is has changed and the date is "22/10/2014", so the format has changed to dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

Comment: I think Jon Skeet has answered me. Question down voted, I just did not know it, jesus some people are like programming nazis. Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> all return me non us format

No, they return you a `DateTime` value. A `DateTime` value doesn't *have* a format. It's just a date and a time. When you want to convert that back into a string, it will use the default format for your current culture unless you say otherwise.

It's important to differentiate between the data stored in a value (a date and time) and string representations of that value.

To give a similar example, what would you expect the result of this code to be?

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32("FF", 16);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Would you expect "255" or "FF"? It's 255, because the default format for converting an `int` to a string is decimal. It doesn't matter that the value was originally parsed from hex - that's not part of the value. Apply the exact same logic to `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that is the answer - lack of knowledge from my side.